# How to check string in string with not exact same values?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm working with Pandas. I need to create a new column in a dataframe according to conditions in other columns. I try to look for each value in a series if it contains a value (a condition to return text).This works when the values are exactly the same but not when the value is only a part of the value of the series

I also tried with str.contains but I never succeeded
The code who works with exact values :

```
if ("something" in df2["Symptom"].values):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

And i got a "no" when it's not the same values.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Symptom':["I am something", 'I am not', 'Something 2']})

if df2["Symptom"].str.contains('Something').any():
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

`OUTPUT: YES`

And If you do the following:

```
if df2["Symptom"].str.contains('Something').all():
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

`OUTPUT: NO`

Comment: I can't do it with "in" ?

Comment: `df2["Symptom"].isin(['Something'])` will look for the exact match

Comment: With .str.contains, i got the error : 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
Because df2["Symptom"] is already a str. I don't know how to resolve this

Comment: Are you sure you are applying this to pandas column?

Comment: My apply is : 

df2["A"] = df2.swifter.apply(conditions, axis=1)

When the conditions are full if - elif - else, like this :

elif df2["Symptom"].str.contains("A").any() :                                                                                       
        if df2["Things"].str.contains("B").any() :

So i create a new columns with conditions when they conditions are str from others columns

Comment: Update : df2["Symptom"] is a pandas series when i check outside the code